# Building a string from a given format and unknown number of arguments

Tags: c, arguments, printf

I have the following code in order to build a string from a given argument list:

```
void MyLog
(
    const char * formatPtr,
    ...
)
{
    va_list args;

    char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];

    /* Initializing the buffer */
    memset(buffer, NULL, BUFFER_LENGTH);

    /* Formatting the arguments */
    va_start(args, formatPtr);
    vsprintf(buffer, formatPtr, args);
    va_end(args);

    /* Print arguments as a formatted string */
    printf(buffer);

}
```

This code is prone to buffer overflow if the arguments length exceeds `BUFFER_LENGTH`. Now, I have a constraint which allows me to use only static allocations, as in `buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH]`.
How can I modify this code in order to provide a correct solution for providing a null terminated string that contains the formatted arguments list, in which if the formatted arguments string length exceeded `BUFFER_LENGTH` then the resulting string will contain the arguments until the last argument which fits to `BUFFER_LENGTH` maximal length.

A proper solution will be to use `char* result = getFormattedString(formatPtr, args)` but I am not aware of such existing function in C libraries.

Comment: `sprintf(buffer, formatPtr, args);` - I guess you'd mean `vsprintf()`.

Comment: `memset` wants an `int` as value (not a pointer like `NULL`), change to `memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH);`

Comment: Please don't edit the question with suggestions from the answer as this makes the post confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of the function sprintf in your example is not correct. You need the function vsprintf.

The function vsnprintf is the function you're looking for, as it has an additional parameter that determines the size of the buffer.

Comment: I have edited my question. `vsprintf()` still not helps me.

Comment: @user2162550 The function that does help you is mentioned in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @user2162550 Note that answer said vs**n**printf

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have missed the `n` letter. I'll accept your answer.